# Synchronize on two String objects

Tags: java, string, concurrency, synchronization

I found answers only for synchronization on one String object, but not two.

It's not a real task, but an assignment. I have SomeLibrary that transfers money from one account to another. I can't access Account object to lock on it. I can only use SomeLibrary.transfer(String from, String to), which is not thread safe. I have method with account ID's as strings. I need to lock on both of these strings without deadlocks.

What I did so far is:

1. Created new Strings with .intern method (String fr = from.intern()). But it's bad practice and I'm not allowed to use this method. But it worked.
2. Created new String from old (String fr = new String(from)). This also worked (I didn't have deadlocks) but I have suspicions about this solution.

Is there other way to lock on both Strings?

I tried to use ConcurrentHashMap and put Strings there, but it didn't work.

May be there is a way to put Strings inside some objects, but where these objects should be created? I can create them inside transfer() but synchronization on a local variable is not good practice either.

My method is:

```
public void transfer(String from, String to, int amount) {
        String fr = new String(from);
        String too = new String(to);

        int fromHash = System.identityHashCode(fr);
        int toHash = System.identityHashCode(too);

        if (fromHash < toHash) {
            synchronizedTransfer(from, to, amount, fr, too);
        } else if (fromHash > toHash) {
            synchronizedTransfer(to, from, amount, too, fr);
        } else {
            synchronized (tieLock) {
                synchronizedTransfer(from, to, amount, fr, too);
            }
        }
    }

private void synchronizedTransfer(String from, String to, int amount, String fr, String too) {
        synchronized (fr) {
            synchronized (too) {
                SomeLibrary.transfer(from, to);
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit:

Is there a way to do this without ConcurrentHashMap? Because this map could get really big and it's not good for performance

Comment: try using StringBuffer. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can synchronize on both objects by using nested synchronized blocks and a data structure in which dedicated synchronization objects are stored.
To prevent any deadlocks I would compare the two Strings lexicographically:

```
private static final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> syncMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void transfer(String from, String to, int amount) {
        Object syncFrom = syncMap.computeIfAbsent(from, s -> new Object());
        Object syncTo = syncMap.computeIfAbsent(to, s -> new Object());

        int comparingResult = from.compareTo(to);

        if (comparingResult > 0) {
            synchronized (syncFrom) {
                synchronized (syncTo) {
                    SomeLibrary.transfer(from, to);
                }
            }
        } else if (comparingResult < 0) {
            synchronized (syncTo) {
                synchronized (syncFrom) {
                    SomeLibrary.transfer(from, to);
                }
            }
        } else {
                synchronized (syncFrom) { // syncFrom == syncTo
                    SomeLibrary.transfer(from, to);
                }
        }
    }
```

If you are not familiar with lambda expressions:

```
Object syncFrom = syncMap.computeIfAbsent(from, s -> new Object());
```

is equivalent to

```
Object syncFrom;
synchronized (syncMap) {
    syncFrom = syncMap.get(from);
    if (syncFrom == null) {
        syncFrom = new Object();
        syncMap.put(from, syncFrom);
    }
}
```

Comment: But this is Synchronization on method parameter and it's considered not good for multithreading

Comment: You're right! It works as long as you have the same Object (same reference). I forgot that you are dealing with Strings that (may) not have the same reference... I changed my answer so it should definitely work now.

Comment: This code is still broken. There is no plausible reason to use a different lock object (`syncOnEquals`) when source and target are the same. That way, it can overlap with other transfers from or to that account. When you have fixed that, you can replace `Hashtable` with `ConcurrentHashMap`; it does not require locking the entire hash map but still does the right thing.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without ConcurrentHashMap? Because this map could get really big and it's not good for performance

Comment: If you do want any deadlocks: No.
You will need a data structure to store the sync objects.
Another option is to simply use a class which implements Comparable or does provide a Comparator instead of using Strings.

Answer (score 0):

What must be clear, is that for a *transfer* (from, to) all (from, *), (*, from), (*, to), (to, *) *transfers* might need to be guarded.

The only way to do that is to synchronize of from and synchronize on to. This could cause a *dead lock* when there is a *transfer* (to, from). For that one can order from and to so that synchronisation AAA comes before synchronisation BBB.

An other approach is to have atomic *deposit* (from, -amount), *deposit* (to, amount)
and do all in a transaction that can be rolled back.

Now on the synchronisation object: this must be a unique Object instance. You could put use the account ID String, as put in a `Map` (`Set`). As such you have a unique object as key in the map. Of course the map operations suffer from concurrency too, use: `Collections.synchronizedMap`. And you need to update it, add/remove account IDs.

As *transactions* are a separate topic, nest two synchronisations in canonical order.